# Set Glyphicon as background image with css

Tags: css, background-image, glyphicons

I would like to use a glypicon using css.

The original HTML uses a background image which I would like to replace. I can't edit the html, so I want to modify the background image using css to a Glyphicon. I would like to use glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right. I know I could replace the .gif file but I would like to avoid having to do that.

This is the HTML were I need to modify the css

```
<img title="My Title" class="handle icon-navigate_right medium" alt="My alt Text" src="assets/images/transparent.gif">
```

At the moment I have added in my css

```
 .icon-navigate_right {background-image:none;}
```

and it is working, but I don't know how to now add a new background image that is a Glyphicon.

If I add something like

```
.icon-navigate_right:before{
  content:"\2b";
  font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
  line-height:1;
  margin:5px;

}
```

It won't display anything. Also I am not sure what content:"\2b" means.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance Tess

Comment: Hi, regarding your code and question I assume you're using FontAwesome or something similar. In fact the icons are not images but font, that's the reason of the `content` instruction, it tell the font wich character to use, and to each character there is a 'letter' wich here translate into an image (because of the font Glyphicons Halflings used). So you can't use it to do a background image because backgrounds are working with images and not fonts.

Comment: As Jaay has said the icon is a font so you cannot use an image tag - change it to a span and it will work: http://www.bootply.com/mqIZIVDqSb.  The `\2b` is the hex code for the plus symbol: http://ascii.cl/